# RapidSMS Twilio Django - SMS Application Architecture

Tags: django, sms, twilio

I am learning SMS application dev with RapidSMS Django. I came across rapidsms-twilio for backend. I am lost here and trying to make sense of overall architecture and technologies associated with each layer. It will help me in future research of better alternatives. Similar to web applications JS/Ajax/css/html are front end tech with java in app layer and db on backend how could i layout SMS application framework?

From my understanding Twilio will provide a number so whenever text is received on number it will receive it in SMMP format and convert it to HTTP and call app server URL mapped against it which could be in django. Where and what does rapidsms do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I have never used RapidSMS, but as far as I can tell, it does the [handling and sending of SMS](http://rapidsms.readthedocs.io/en/develop/intro/overview.html) via a chosen [backend](http://rapidsms.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/backends/index.html) processor that receives and sends SMS messages. It comes with some [built in backends](http://rapidsms.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/backends/index.html), like [Kannel which is an SMS gateway](http://rapidsms.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/backends/kannel.html#kannel-configuration), but there are third party backends available too.

rapidsms-twilio is a third party backend that allows you to use RapidSMS as the dashboard/user interface and [send and receive messages via Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)

Comment: Thanks @philnash for an answer. i was able to develop sms app with twilio and rapidsms.